# Android: How to mark sample string in layout file

Tags: android

I have many lists in my android app. I'm using strings as samples (android:text) for the layout preview.

Example:

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/firstname"
android:layout_width="0dp"
style="@style/TextListStyle"
android:text="Peter"/>
```

Android studio is marking this as a warning but I don't want to put every sample string into the strings.xml file.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: sorry couldn't understand the question. You are writing style and asking about string ??

Comment: `A Warning is not an Error`. Lint is simply complaining that you are using a **hard coded** string instead of storing your strings in strings.xml.

Comment: Don't know why it was uprated but anyway. @Der Golem; I want to supress this warning, sometimes there are possibilities with annotaion in Java Code or some other hints in xml.

Comment: no I meant the question was not that clear, that's all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it just for preview consider this:

```
tools:text="John Doe"
```

More Infos on [Designtime Layout Attributes](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes).

Answer (score 1):

Add `tools:ignore="HardcodedText"` in your root layout, like:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
```

However this is quite bad practice, for the reasons stated [here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks):

> Hardcoding text attributes directly in layout files is bad for several
>   reasons:
>
> - When creating configuration variations (for example for landscape or
>     portrait) you have to repeat the actual text (and keep it up to date when
>     making changes)
> - The application cannot be translated to other languages by just adding new
>     translations for existing string resources.

Comment: Great, this is what I've searched for. The strings I'm using there will everytime replaced with dynamic data.

Comment: Thats just a ignore for the tooling, consider using my above Answer as it avoids having strings in your layout you don't need.